# encrypt json file in parallel with python

Tags: python, json, parallel-processing

I have a json file that its records are like

> ```
>   "emp_no" : 10002,
>     "birth_date" : "1964-06-02",
>     "first_name" : "Bezalel",
>     "last_name" : "Simmel",
>     "gender" : "F",
>     "hire_date" : "1985-11-21"
> ```

now I want to encrypt emp_no with OPE!
I want to do this in parallel so I try

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing
import json
from ope import OPE

r_k = OPE.generate_key()
cipher = OPE(r_k)
f = open('/home/carol/test.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)

def ope_enc(x):
    x['emp_no'] = cipher.encrypt(x['emp_no'])
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = my json file
    with closing(Pool(processes=5)) as pool:
        result = pool.map(ope_enc, data)
    h = open('/home/carol/res.json', 'w')

    json.dump(result, h)
```

but it not works!
can anyone help me?!
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`closing` should not be used in this case, I think you meant that:

```
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        result = pool.map(ope_enc, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below (using dummy encryption)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing
import json

data = [{"emp_no": 10002,
        "birth_date": "1964-06-02",
        "first_name": "Bezalel",
        "last_name": "Simmel",
        "gender": "F",
        "hire_date": "1985-11-21"}, {"emp_no": 100044,
                                     "birth_date": "1964-06-02",
                                     "first_name": "Bezalel",
                                     "last_name": "Simmel",
                                     "gender": "F",
                                     "hire_date": "1985-11-21"}]


def ope_enc(x):
    # Just add 1
    x['emp_no'] = x['emp_no'] + 1
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with closing(Pool(processes=5)) as pool:
        result = pool.map(ope_enc, data)
    with open('res.json', 'w') as out:
        json.dump(result, out)
```

res.json

```
 [
   {
     "emp_no": 10003,
     "birth_date": "1964-06-02",
     "first_name": "Bezalel",
     "last_name": "Simmel",
      "gender": "F",
      "hire_date": "1985-11-21"
  },
  {
      "emp_no": 100045,
      "birth_date": "1964-06-02",
      "first_name": "Bezalel",
      "last_name": "Simmel",
       "gender": "F",
       "hire_date": "1985-11-21"
  }
]
```

Comment: what's difference between it and my code?! I just want to do that in parallel.

Comment: The main difference is that the code I have submitted works :-)

Comment: yes it works! my code is also works!!!! my problem is the time!!!! you have just 2 records! it can not show time optimization!!!!

Comment: OK. I got it. Maybe you encryption algorithm is slow. Try to measure its execution time. How many entries do you have and what is your pool size?